# Facing problems dealing With Google Maps Android

Tags: android, multithreading, google-maps, timer, marker

i am using below code to run my `getLatLngWrkr();` function after 3 seconds but when timer starts and `getLatLngWrkr();`gets call the code which places Marker does not work.But when i run the function `getLatLngWrkr()` without Timer it works properly.

here is the some line to place marker to map and it does not work if i call the function through Timer

```
marker=googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newLatLng(Double.parseDouble(lati), Double.parseDouble(longi))).title(  lati+longi));

Here is Timer Function
Timer time = new Timer();
        time.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e("test","tiemr");
                getLatLngWrkr();
            }
        },0, 3000);
```

Comment: please post your  getLatLngWrkr(); function too.//

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a `TimerTask` the task is performed on a separate thread and not the ui thread.  You need to call `getLatLngWrkr` using `runOnUiThread`:

```
    Timer time = new Timer();
    time.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("test","tiemr");

            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getLatLngWrkr();
            }
        });


        }
    },0, 3000);
```

Replace `MainActviity` with the name of your activity.

Comment: And can you tell me how to stop this thread when application is closed?